# FreeForm Pro - How do I edit my confirmation screen?

Tags: solspace-freeform, confirmation

How do I edit the confirmation screen that a user sees after selecting "Submit"?

Right now it says "Thank you for your submission!" and I'd like to add more engaging content.

Comment: that all depends on how things are setup. Is it an AJAX form handler? If so, you'll need to check the .js files.
Otherwise you can setup a page/template and set the return parameter to that template (like return="template_group/template")

Answer (score 1):

If the "return" parameter doesn't meet your needs, if you use Composer, you can add the Composer fieldtype to your fieldgroup, which has two definitions: your form, and the thank you page.